# How can I create dynamic links with swig, so I can active / non-active classes on the links?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, swig-template

How can I create dynamic links with swig templates, so I can active / non-active classes on the links?

I want to be able to show which links are active on my template.html page without having to send the request object through to the template everytime

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> without having to send the request object through to the template everytime

Sending the request object is going to be the best-case scenario and the easiest to automate. Sending the request object isn't going to cause any performance-related issues, nor cause anything bad to happen. It'd be easy for you to write a custom response handler for express to always include the request object in the data sent to the template.

Alternatively, though, you can set a variable in the top of every template and the do an `if` statement on every link.

*mypage.html*

```
{% set current_page = 'mypage' %}
{% extends "layout.html" %}
```

*layout.html*

```
<a href="/mypage" class="{% if current_page == 'mypage' %}current{% endif %}">My Page</a>
```

Comment: Awesome, that works a treat, I have subtemplates for every section of my app so I have set SectionName there and that sets the main menu active.. saves me having to do it on every page. thanks heaps.